# How to add element type to JSX namespace in a separate package?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I'm creating a package with typescript types for Polymer library. These types will be used in React projects so I need to add types for elements to `JSX.IntrinsicElements`.

```js
import { HTMLAttributes } from "react";
import { PolymerElement } from '@polymer/polymer';

interface CoralTooltipAttributes<T> extends HTMLAttributes<T> {
    selector?: string;
    condition?: Function;
    renderer?: Function;
    position?: string;
    transitionStyle?: string;
}

interface CoralTooltipElement extends PolymerElement {}

declare namespace JSX {
    interface IntrinsicElements {
        "coral-tooltip": React.DetailedHTMLProps<CoralTooltipAttributes<CoralTooltipElement>, CoralTooltipElement>;
    }
}
```

I've added `"types": "index"` to my `package.json`.
The problem is when I npm link this package with my project, it just not see `"coral-tooltip"` and shows an error like this

> ButtonGroup.tsx(32,21): error TS2339: Property 'coral-tooltip' does
>   not exist on type 'JSX.IntrinsicElements'.

Also I've added to the project's tsconfig.json this string: `"types": [ "elf-typings" ]`

What should I do so the types for elements could be succesfully imported by typescript?

Comment: probably your typing file is not picked up. Did you try to change typeRoots in tsconfig? It should be set to 'node_modules/types', 'node_modules/<your-package>' in your case

Comment: Actually it's not quite work. I have to add `import 'my-package-with-types';` in the .tsx file and only then typescript is able to find types from the package. `types` in package.json doesn't help.

Answer (score 0):

As Doğancan Arabacı offered

> probably your typing file is not picked up. Did you try to change
>   typeRoots in tsconfig? It should be set to 'node_modules/types',
>   'node_modules/' in your case

Also at the top of `.tsx` files must be inserted this string

```
/// <reference types="my-package-with-types" />
```